# Can't install discord.py to pycharm?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to install discord.py v.2.3.2 but This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip

It's said `Failed building wheel for multidict` and `Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects`

**Command output:**

```
Collecting discord.py==2.3.2
  Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4 (from discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (7.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=17.3.0 in c:\users\wrpcr\pycharmprojects\chinchabot\.venv\lib\site-packages (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2) (23.1.0)
Collecting multidict<7.0,>=4.5 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached multidict-6.0.4.tar.gz (51 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Installing backend dependencies: started
  Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting yarl<2.0,>=1.0 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (32 kB)
Collecting frozenlist>=1.1.1 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached frozenlist-1.4.0.tar.gz (90 kB)
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting aiosignal>=1.1.2 (from aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached aiosignal-1.3.1-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0 (from yarl<2.0,>=1.0->aiohttp<4,>=3.7.4->discord.py==2.3.2)
  Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Using cached discord.py-2.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (1.1 MB)
Using cached aiohttp-3.9.1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (362 kB)
Using cached yarl-1.9.4-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl (76 kB)
Using cached idna-3.6-py3-none-any.whl (61 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: frozenlist, multidict
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml): started
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
Failed to build frozenlist multidict

  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for frozenlist (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [33 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  running egg_info
  writing frozenlist.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to frozenlist.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to frozenlist.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'frozenlist\*.html'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'frozenlist.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  copying frozenlist\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\_frozenlist.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  copying frozenlist\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\frozenlist
  running build_ext
  building 'frozenlist._frozenlist' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for frozenlist
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  Building wheel for multidict (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  exit code: 1
  
  [74 lines of output]
  *********************
  * Accelerated build *
  *********************
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_compat.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_base.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\_multidict_py.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  running egg_info
  writing multidict.egg-info\PKG-INFO
  writing dependency_links to multidict.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
  writing top-level names to multidict.egg-info\top_level.txt
  reading manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
  warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\_multidict.html'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.so'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  warning: no previously-included files found matching 'multidict\*.pyd'
  no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
  adding license file 'LICENSE'
  writing manifest file 'multidict.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
  C:\Users\wrpcr\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-0ldh3ecx\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\build_py.py:207: _Warning: Package 'multidict._multilib' is absent from the `packages` configuration.
  !!
  
          ********************************************************************************
          ############################
          # Package would be ignored #
          ############################
          Python recognizes 'multidict._multilib' as an importable package[^1],
          but it is absent from setuptools' `packages` configuration.
  
          This leads to an ambiguous overall configuration. If you want to distribute this
          package, please make sure that 'multidict._multilib' is explicitly added
          to the `packages` configuration field.
  
          Alternatively, you can also rely on setuptools' discovery methods
          (for example by using `find_namespace_packages(...)`/`find_namespace:`
          instead of `find_packages(...)`/`find:`).
  
          You can read more about "package discovery" on setuptools documentation page:
  
          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html
  
          If you don't want 'multidict._multilib' to be distributed and are
          already explicitly excluding 'multidict._multilib' via
          `find_namespace_packages(...)/find_namespace` or `find_packages(...)/find`,
          you can try to use `exclude_package_data`, or `include-package-data=False` in
          combination with a more fine grained `package-data` configuration.
  
          You can read more about "package data files" on setuptools documentation page:
  
          - https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html
  
  
          [^1]: For Python, any directory (with suitable naming) can be imported,
                even if it does not contain any `.py` files.
                On the other hand, currently there is no concept of package data
                directory, all directories are treated like packages.
          ********************************************************************************
  
  !!
    check.warn(importable)
  copying multidict\__init__.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  copying multidict\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-312\multidict
  running build_ext
  building 'multidict._multidict' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for multidict
ERROR: Could not build wheels for frozenlist, multidict, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I try to type in terminal "pip install discord.py" and "pip install -m discord.py --upgrade" but it doesn't work

Comment: did you see in error `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/` ? did you install `Visual C++ 14.0`? It needs it to compile some C/C++ code. You can see this problem in many other questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: we didn't get your python version

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify your python version but I suspect from similar issues raised in https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/discussions/5898 and https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/5984 that you're probably using an unsupported version of python. Please note that python 3.9 was pretty new as at the time those issues where raised and should now work fine but you can see the similarity with yours from the Tracebacks.

Currently, the latest version of discord.py (i.e. 2.3.2) only supports Python 3.8, 3.9 and 3.10. So a good place to begin is to check your python version.

From the issues raised in the links **(I suggest you look at it)**, I assume you're using windows. If you check that your python version is compatible with discord, you might also want to follow the suggestion of your Traceback `error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required.` So visit https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ and install `Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0` or greater. This should hopefully resolve your issues.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the [Visual Studio Tools](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/en/downloads/?q=build%20tools)

https://aka.ms/vs/17/release/vs_BuildTools.exe (recent instant download link)

I had the same problem and it was fixed as soon as I installed the tools.